# How override the default BCryptPasswordEncoder created through PasswordEncoderFactories?

Tags: spring-security, bcrypt

I know that in Spring Security would arise the following:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"
```

And the solution is define a `PasswordEncoder`. For simplicity is possible define the following:

```java
@Bean
PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Now, behind the scene the `createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()` method is defined how (it so far until currently for Spring Security 5.4.2) (See the [PasswordEncoderFactories](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/factory/PasswordEncoderFactories.java) class for more details):

```java
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static PasswordEncoder createDelegatingPasswordEncoder() {
    String encodingId = "bcrypt";
    Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
    encoders.put(encodingId, new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    encoders.put("ldap", new org.springframework.security.crypto.password.LdapShaPasswordEncoder());
    encoders.put("MD4", new org.springframework.security.crypto.password.Md4PasswordEncoder());
    encoders.put("MD5", new org.springframework.security.crypto.password.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder("MD5"));
    encoders.put("noop", org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
    encoders.put("pbkdf2", new Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder());
    encoders.put("scrypt", new SCryptPasswordEncoder());
    encoders.put("SHA-1", new org.springframework.security.crypto.password.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder("SHA-1"));
    encoders.put("SHA-256",
            new org.springframework.security.crypto.password.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder("SHA-256"));
    encoders.put("sha256", new org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder());
    encoders.put("argon2", new Argon2PasswordEncoder());
    return new DelegatingPasswordEncoder(encodingId, encoders);
}
```

Now about the [BCryptPasswordEncoder](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.java) class, it works with some defaults such as:

- version: `$2a`
- strength: `10`

What happens if declare the following:

```java
@Bean
PasswordEncoder bcryptEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(BCryptVersion.$2Y, 12);
}
```

How I can add or override the *default* `BCryptPasswordEncoder` created with the *custom* `BCryptPasswordEncoder` into the default settings? I want keep all the other defaults

**Note**: In the [PasswordEncoderFactories](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/factory/PasswordEncoderFactories.java) class (for the `createDelegatingPasswordEncoder` method), the [DelegatingPasswordEncoder](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java) class is used behind the scenes. That class does not offer an approach to override too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are creating a **new application**, you very likely do not need `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` and instead should use an adaptive one-way function password encoder, for example `BCryptPasswordEncoder`.

To do this, you can expose a `BCryptPasswordEncoder` as a bean.

```java
@Bean
PasswordEncoder bcryptEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(BCryptVersion.$2Y, 12);
}
```

Then, when a user registers, you can encode their password using the `BCryptPasswordEncoder` before saving it to your data store. For example:

```java
UserDetails userDetails = User
        .withUsername(username)
        .password(bcryptEncoder.encode(password))
        .roles("USER")
        .build();
```

If you are migrating an **existing application**, that is where `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` is useful.

The `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` allows for validating passwords in multiple formats. It uses the prefixed ID (e.g `{bcrypt}`) to look up which `PasswordEncoder` should be used.

Consider a legacy application that uses plaintext passwords.
To migrate the application, you would prefix the plaintext passwords with `{noop}` and use a `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` like the one below:

```java
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder delegatingPasswordEncoder() {
    Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
    encoders.put("bcrypt", new BCryptPasswordEncoder(BCryptVersion.$2Y, 12));
    encoders.put("noop", NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
    return new DelegatingPasswordEncoder("bcrypt", encoders);
}
```

This `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` will encode and validate any newly created password using the `BCryptPasswordEncoder`, while still being able to validate the legacy plaintext passwords using the `NoOpPasswordEncoder`.

Spring Security provides the `PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()` method as a convenient default, but it is unlikely that your application uses that many different password encodings.
What is more likely, is that your application uses 2 different encodings, the legacy one (e.g noop) and the modern one (e.g bcrypt), in which case you can use a `PasswordEncoder` similar to the `delegatingPasswordEncoder` described above.

The point of these examples is to say that in most situations you do not need the defaults that are set in `createDelegatingPasswordEncoder`. However, if you still want to use the encoders from `createDelegatingPasswordEncoder`, except for `bcrypt`, you can use a `PasswordEncoder` that looks like this:

```java
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder delegatingPasswordEncoder() {
    Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
    // Use this encoder for bcrypt
    encoders.put("bcrypt", new BCryptPasswordEncoder(BCryptVersion.$2Y, 12));
    DelegatingPasswordEncoder delegatingPasswordEncoder =
            new DelegatingPasswordEncoder("bcrypt", encoders);

    PasswordEncoder defaultDelegatingPasswordEncoder =
            PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    // If a password ID does not match "bcrypt", use defaultDelegatingPasswordEncoder
    delegatingPasswordEncoder.setDefaultPasswordEncoderForMatches(defaultDelegatingPasswordEncoder);

    return delegatingPasswordEncoder;
}
```

Comment: The official documentation recommends to use DelegatingPasswordEncoder also for new applications, in case password storage approach changes again in the future. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/authentication/password-storage.html#authentication-password-storage-dpe